# Map-icons not visible in the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I placed the map in my application and I put markers in it. These markers represent the means they have to follow a path, and then "move" through the map. 
The markers that I have placed the "map.icons" and I have declared this way:

```
var marker = new Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5,
        icon: {
        path: MAP_PIN,
        fillColor: "#339EF2",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '',
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 0.3,
        rotation: 35
        },
        label: "<i class='icon icon-car' style='color:white; margin-left: 10px; font-size: 22px'></i>"
    });
```

Where do I see a marker with the middle interested drawn.

The problem is that (not always) the marker is not drawn, perhaps due to the zoom that it makes the map based on the location of the path, because if I move the map you see the same.

it is possible to solve the problem of marker that you can not see?

Many thanks for your reply. 
dave

Examples:

Before moving of the Map:

[image: Before]

After moving the Map:

[image: After]

Comment: What is `Marker()` ?

Comment: Marker() is the google.maps.Marker(), but said the library "map-icons.js" that allows me to define the marker as svg and label as "font icon."

Comment: can you provide a demo of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a map of "dynamic" type, ie that the marker must follow a path, it sometimes does not appear, while a map "static" always remains visible.

I solved the problem by replacing the svg with an image (the same!) Of the same marker but leaving the label as decided in the imported library.

Many thanks,

dave